# Setting tabindex in MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is this possible at all? When I create a form using MonoTouch.Dialog, it comes automatically with the "next" button, but that jumps to the last input in the form. Is this a bug, or is it because I have to set a `tabindex` of sorts to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer on github. My bad, I should've looked more thoroughly there first. On the `GetCell` of the `EntryElement`, inside the `entry.ShouldReturn` `foreach`-loop, you need to break after setting focus to the next input.

https://github.com/SuperYeti/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L1096

Answer (score 0):

It should jump to the next input line, is that not the behavior that you are experiencing?

A test case would shed some light.

Comment: I also downloaded the Sample project, and I'm getting the same behaviour there. Clicking the top input, and then clicking next will send focus to the last input, and not the next. I'll try to get a test case up and running tomorrow.

Comment: In the Sample project that follows MonoTouch.Dialog, in the Assorted Elements, this error is reproduced. If you click the email-input first, then click next on the keyboard, it jumps two inputs down, to the last input (phone). It probably should jump to Url instead, which is the next input in line.

Comment: Please file a bug report on the github project.